# Django add value to hidden field inline formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django 1.11. I am trying to add a value to a hidden field in an inline formset form. I have tried unsuccessfully inserting the hidden field value at various points of `def get_context_data` and `def form_valid`. The code I am using is as follows:

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class DocumentCreate(CreateView):
    model = DocumentClient
    success_url = reverse_lazy('documents')
    form_class = DocumentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(DocumentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['docform'] = DocumentFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['docform'] = DocumentFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        docform = context['docform']
        if docform.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            docform.instance = self.object
            docform.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('documents')
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentClient
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
            'cnum': HiddenInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields['cnum'].required = False


class DocumentDetailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentDetail
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
            'document_date': DateInput(),
                    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DocumentDetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['document_description'].required = False

DocumentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(DocumentClient, DocumentDetail, form=DocumentDetailForm, extra=10, can_delete=False)
```

The hidden field `'cnum'` is that what I am trying to insert a value for capturing in the model. Is anyone able to provide any guidance on how to acheive this? Any assistance is gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DocumentCreate`, have you tried this?

```
class DocumentCreate(CreateView):
    def get_initial(self):
        # Get initial value from kwargs (If needed) and save as instance variable.
        self.cnum_val = self.kwargs.get('cnum_value')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Insert your desired value to cnum (or you can simply forget get_initial and supply whatever value here)
        form.instance.cnum = self.cnum_val 
        self.object = form.save()
        ...
        self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

`form.instance` refers to the unsaved model object used by the form

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) also.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I used your  def form_valid(self, form):  method.